# Grails mockDomain save not saving

Tags: unit-testing, grails, mocking

I'm writing a unit test for some simple methods.  The issue I am having is that 'save' is not working for my domain object even though the domain should be mocked.  When calling validate on the domain object, it comes back as true.  I've even surrounded the object with try/catch to make sure it wasn't throwing any odd errors and that is not the case.  Code below for call and test.

```
void test()
{
    mockDomain(MyDomain)
    Map map1= ["asdf":" "]
    Map map2 = ["asdf":123]
    InputObject input = new InputObject()
            input.setForeignId("1") //not a constraint
    input.setMap1(map1)
    input.setMap2(map2 )
    service.methodUnderTest(profile)
    List list = MyDomain.getAll()
    assertEquals 1, l.size() //FAILS
}

def persistPublishGuids(InputObject input)
{
    try{
    HashMap map1 = input.map1
    for ( e in map1 )
    {
        String key= e.getKey()
        String value = e.value
        long size = input.map2.get(key)
        MyDomain domain = new MyDomain (id:guid, field1:value, field2:input.foreignId, field3:size)
        domain.save()
    }
    } catch(ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

Comment: It would probably be helpful if this were a [sscce](http://sscce.org/). What you've posted can't be run by itself. Try to produce the simplest example that will execute and reproduce the issue and post that. It's possible that in doing so you will uncover the root of the problem, and if not, you'll have a much clearer example for someone to help with.

Comment: I would, but I figured it out.  The needed to run grails clean, then clean/rebuild the project in STS.  I only found this out because when I started to write another test this morning and it claimed that there was no method 'save()' on one of my domain objects.  Googling that led me to the clean and rebuild solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the grails app needed to be cleaned and the project rebuilt.

Comment: this is the plague of grails... I spend more time cleaning/compiling than coding stuff...GrrrRails.

Comment: I haven't had this problem in ages.  You must have a setup issue.

Comment: I was speaking in general: 'clean' grails is a bit the same as windows reboot... it cure almost every odd behavior...

Answer (score 4):

I would also recommend setting the flush and failOnError flags to true when saving domain objects in tests. 'flush:true' ensures the object is saved immediately. Without failOnError validation errors will mean the object is NOT saved and this can easily be missed.

```
domainObject.save(flush:true, failOnError: true)
```

It is also worth considering setting the validate flag to false if you don't want to setup base data for all fields in the test

`domainObject.save(validate: false)`

See the [Grails domain object save docs for full information](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/save.html)